# why is there deadlock when using wait group and channel in go?

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, waitgroup

I wanna use setter function to send 0-9 into ***ch1*** channel ,and computer function square the number from ***ch1***， then send the result into ***ch2*** channel . however, i get panic when running this code.  would anybody explain why this situation happened, i totally confused.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func setter(ch1 chan int, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    for i:= 0; i< 10;i++ {
        fmt.Println("setter:", i)
        ch1 <- i
    }
    close(ch1)
    wg.Done()
}

func computer(ch1 chan int, ch2 chan int, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    for true {
        tmp, ok := <- ch1
        if !ok {
            fmt.Println("computer: there is no value in ch1")
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("computer:", tmp*tmp)
        ch2 <- tmp*tmp
    }
    close(ch2)
    wg.Done()
}

func main(){
    ch1 := make(chan int,1)
    ch2 := make(chan int,1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    go setter(ch1, wg)
    go computer(ch1, ch2, wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

the error like this :

```
setter: 0
setter: 1
setter: 2
computer: 0
computer: 1
setter: 3
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc000196008)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x45
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc000196000)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x65
main.main()
        /Users/koujianyuan/Desktop/code/project/go/chan/communication/demo.go:50 +0x13b

goroutine 18 [chan send]:
main.setter(0xc000194000, 0x200000000, 0xc000000000)
        /Users/koujianyuan/Desktop/code/project/go/chan/communication/demo.go:16 +0x107
created by main.main
        /Users/koujianyuan/Desktop/code/project/go/chan/communication/demo.go:47 +0xdb

goroutine 19 [chan send]:
main.computer(0xc000194000, 0xc000194070, 0x200000000, 0x0)
        /Users/koujianyuan/Desktop/code/project/go/chan/communication/demo.go:35 +0x11c
created by main.main
        /Users/koujianyuan/Desktop/code/project/go/chan/communication/demo.go:48 +0x12d
```

Comment: Use `wg *sync.WaitGroup` in both functions and pass `&wg` to the goroutines.

Comment: You are not reading from `ch2` anywhere, so it blocks when you put the second value in it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why there is a deadlock is that you are not reading from the `ch2` channel. The `ch2` channel block when you try to put the value in it for the second time (the first time it passes because it is a buffered channel of 1). When putting the value in the `ch2` channel blocks, it also blocks reading the value from the `ch1` channel, so the `setter` goroutine cannot put values in `ch1` anymore.

With both `ch1` and `ch2` channels blocked, both `setter` and `computer` goroutines cannot finish, which causes a deadlock.

[Here](https://go.dev/play/p/IW7mDaQvqxw) is a working example. I've added the `reader` function that read from the `ch2` channel.

```
// The rest of the code is the same except I've changed the functions to use *sync.Waitgroup

func reader(ch chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for i := range ch {
        fmt.Println("reading from channel", i)
    }
    fmt.Println("reader exiting")
}

func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int, 1)
    ch2 := make(chan int, 1)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(3)
    go reader(ch2, &wg)
    go setter(ch1, &wg)
    go computer(ch1, ch2, &wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```